# RxJs Zip only takes the first value from the sent stream

Tags: rxjs

I have the following code using [RxJs Zip](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip) operator:

```
of(1, 2, 3)
  .pipe(zip(of(5), of(10)))
  .subscribe((a) => console.log(a));
```

The output will be

```
[1, 5, 10]
```

But what happened to the 2 and 3 values initialized at `of(1, 2, 3)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner observables `of(5)` and `of(10)` only have one element. The static method `zip()` will only emit when all observable emit a corresponding notification.

For eg.

```js
of(1, 2, 3)
  .pipe(zip(of(5, 6, 7), of(10, 11, 12)))
  .subscribe((a) => console.log(a));
```

will emit

```js
[1, 5, 10]
[2, 6, 11]
[3, 7, 12]
```

I must also stress here that the static method [`zip()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#static-method-zip) is deprecated and has since been replaced by the [`zip()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/zip) function. Using the new `zip()` the equivalent for the above would be

```js
import { of, zip } from 'rxjs';

zip(
  of(1, 2, 3), 
  of(5, 6, 7), 
  of(10, 11, 12)
).subscribe((a) => console.log(a));
```